# Is it mandatory for browser vendors to implement relatedTarget as a member of a blur event object?

Tags: javascript, dom, w3c

At first, I'd like to state that I have read (nearly) all the other questions about the `blur` event and `relatedTarget`, and that I have understood how they work together.

However, from the specifications I saw, I haven't understood whether (from the specifications' viewpoint) it is mandatory for browser vendors to implement `relatedTarget` at all.

MDN seems to have evolved to some sort of authoritative specification on its own during the last years. Hence, according to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget), there should be no doubt that `relatedTarget` is always a member of a `blur` event object and references the DOM element where the focus is going to (let's neglect edge cases like tabbing outside the window, tabbing to nested documents and so on).

However, the very same page references the [W3C UI Events Working Draft](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#idl-focusevent) as underlying specification, which states in § 5.2.1.2:

> FocusEventInit . relatedTarget
> The relatedTarget should be initialized to the element losing focus (in the case of a focus or focusin event) or the element gaining focus (in the case of a blur or focusout event).

Here, the usage of the term "should" explicitly means that browser vendors may decide to take a different course: [The W3C draft states that it adheres to RFC2119](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#ui-events-conformance) regarding the usage of such terms. [In RFC2119](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119), on the very first page, we find:

> 3 SHOULD   This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a particular item, but the full implications must be understood and carefully weighed before choosing a different course.

That really makes the impression that browser vendors will do whatever they want at this place.

In contrast and to make my worries even worse, [§ 5.2.4.1. of the W3C draft](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-blur) makes the impression that `relatedTarget` once again *is* to be implemented as part of the `blur` event object.

What should I make out of this?

Please note that I am not asking how browsers actually behave. I just would like to know whether or not the implementation of `relatedTarget` as part of the `blur` event object is mandatory for browser vendors *according to existing specifications (if any) or drafts*.

Comment: I can't give a definitive answer to this, but I note that the text says "should" and not "SHOULD". That means that RFC2119 isn't in play, and "should" here means something  different. The FocusEventInit object is effectively an input provided by the caller of the constructor of the event. Its description is saying what the calller needs to do to make the event be constructed correctly, but it cannot mandate what any caller must do, since the caller might be your code rather than browser code.

Comment: Thank you very much, and +1. I never would have suspected that upper case / lower case really makes a difference. I should have seen this, though, because the W3C draft indeed uses both variants (`SHOULD` and `should`), so I really should have asked myself why this is. If you make your comment an answer, I'll happily accept it.